# Python: how to get difference between two months from integers?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe `df` like the following:

```
df
    A    NUM_YYYYMM
0   a     201605
1   b     201602
2   c     201603
3   d     201601
```

where `type(df['NUM_YYYYMM'])` returns `int`. I want to compute the difference in months between `t0=201612` and the column `df['NUM_YYYYMM']`. So:

```
df
    A    NUM_YYYYMM   deltaT
0   a     201605        7
1   b     201602       10
2   c     201603        9
3   d     201601       11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then to month periods by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), which is subtracted by `Period` from `t0`:

```
t0 = '201612'
t = pd.to_datetime(t0, format='%Y%m').to_period('m')

df['deltaT'] = t - pd.to_datetime(df['NUM_YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m')
print (df)
   A  NUM_YYYYMM deltaT
0  a      201605      7
1  b      201602     10
2  c      201603      9
3  d      201601     11
```

If is possible change format of `t0`:

```
t = pd.Period('2016-12')
df['deltaT'] = t - pd.to_datetime(df['NUM_YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m')
```

Comment: I get an error here `pd.to_datetime(df['NUM_YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m')` that returns `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'to_period'`

Comment: @emax - dont forget for `.dt` ? like `pd.to_datetime(df['NUM_YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m').to_period('m')`, but need `pd.to_datetime(df['NUM_YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m')`

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own subtraction using integer and modulus division given your standard format YYYYMM

```
def my_subtract(x, t0):
    return (t0//100 - x//100)*12 + (t0%100 - x%100)

df['deltaT'] = my_subtract(df.NUM_YYYYMM, 201612)
```

## Output `df`:

```
   A  NUM_YYYYMM  deltaT
0  a      201605       7
1  b      201602      10
2  c      201603       9
3  d      201601      11
```